# HTML PDF table with input cells copying row values

Tags: html, pdf, input

I am a rookie with HTML and CSS. I have a question which I hope has a simple answer. I am building a table where one of the columns is an input. My issue is that when I type the input in one of the columns, it gets automatically copied to all of the other rows.

In summary, even if I have 10 rows, I am only able to enter one value since that one value keeps getting copied in every row. I need to be able to enter a unique value in each of the rows.

Here is the code for that column:

```
<td align="center" style="border: 0.1px; width: 81px; text-align: center;">
    <input disabled="true" style="width: 40px" type="text" id="id1" name="quantity" />
</td>
```

and here is also a screenshot of the table where the values get copied

[image]

After doing some research I was able to find out this is possible via JS but I am limited to just HTML/CSS. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does this have to do with PDF?

Answer (score 0):

does all your inputs with the same id? `id="id1"`, if so you must to give unique id to every input.